# Run a jQuery function after v-for is done in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-resource

Using vue-resource i am able to get data from my api and set it so i can use it in my html , my problem is i want to run a jquery function after v-for is complete so jquery could see elements in my dom , here is my code :

**js**

```
dataUrl = "http://localhost:8081/hesabiha/userSubmissions";

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#campaign",
  methods: {
    getSubmissions: function(){
      this.$http.get(dataUrl, function(submissions){
        this.$set('submissions', submissions);
      });
    },
  },

  ready: function(){
    this.getSubmissions();
  }
});
```

**html**

```
<div v-for="item in submissions" class="grid-item">
    <img v-bind:src="item.field_image[0].url" alt="Hello">
</div>
```

I'm trying to run this function against my page :

```
$('.grid').masonry({
    // options...
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    columnWidth: 200
  });
```

It doesn't work , is there anyway so i can run this jquery function after v-for is complete ?

Comment: to whoever down votes , care to explain your reason !!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
getSubmissions: function(){
  var _this = this
  this.$http.get(dataUrl, function(submissions){
    this.$set('submissions', submissions);
    this.$nextTick(function(){/*here the DOM is ready*/})
  }
}
```

Comment: and when i should call my jquery function ? i don't have problem with my method , my problem is when v-for is done putting data in html i need to call a jquery function !

Comment: Edited see my answer

Comment: it's doesn't work that way , since vue starts rendering view as soon as submission is set , there is no next tick it's async

Comment: Works here, vue will finish v-for before running jquery

Comment: Work with Vue 2 for me,

Answer (score 2):

actually v-for works with life-cycle hooks and it's not working with the first render of vue on DOM it goes with UPDATE DOM so if you put any function after UPDATED 
it will be called after V-for

```
enter code here

methods:{
},

updated({
//your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dataUrl = "http://localhost:8081/hesabiha/userSubmissions";

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#campaign",
  methods: {
    getSubmissions: function(){
      this.$http.get(dataUrl, function(submissions){
        this.$set('submissions', submissions);

        $('.grid').masonry({
            // options...
            itemSelector: '.grid-item',
            columnWidth: 200
        });
      });
    },
  },
  ready: function(){
    this.getSubmissions();
  }
});
```

if this doesnt work you may want to call the .grid after a timeout function for

Comment: no i can't use timeout , man i don't know whats wrong with this community lately , everyone running around and down voting

Comment: in html make sure that vue script you created is imported after jquery, after that either nextTick as gurghet mentioned or setTimeout will work, I had this case before and it was kind of the same only I had to use packery.